# Has anyone colorized VIM opening and closing ( [ { marks?

Tags: vim, atom-editor, text-editor

Coming from Atom - one thing I have come to love is the matching colors for opening and closing curly braces.

Has anyone implemented this sort of colorization for Vim? It's very apparent that Vim recognizes the matching brackets and parentheses and brackets.

here's an image from Atom demonstrating what I've described
[image]

Comment: Yes.  Look for the rainbow-parentheses plugins (there appear to be many now).

Comment: For anyone looking this plugin works well: https://github.com/kien/rainbow_parentheses.vim